# unit test service with external api

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

someone can guide me a little to perform a unit test to this controller and service that queries an external api, I have already done some things I've seen but I do not know if it is correct, I appreciate your help.

photos.service.ts

```
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class PhotosService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

  async getPhotos() {
    return this.httpService.axiosRef.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos`,
    );
  }
}
```

photos.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PhotosService } from './photos.service';

@Controller('photos')
export class PhotosController {
  constructor(private api: PhotosService) {}

  @Get()
  async getPhotos() {
    return this.api.getPhotos();
  }
}
```

photos.controller.spec.ts

```
import { HttpModule } from '@nestjs/axios';
import { HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { PhotosController } from './photos.controller';
import { PhotosService } from './photos.service';

describe('PhotosController', () => {
  let photosController: PhotosController;
  let photosService: PhotosService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [PhotosController],
      providers: [PhotosService],
      imports: [HttpModule],
    }).compile();

    photosController = module.get<PhotosController>(PhotosController);
    photosService = module.get<PhotosService>(PhotosService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(photosController).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('getPhotos', () => {
    it('should return a user', async () => {
      const data = ['test'];
      const response: AxiosResponse<any> = {
        data,
        headers: {},
        config: { url: 'http://localhost:3000/mockUrl' },
        status: 500,
        statusText: 'OK',
      };
      jest
        .spyOn(photosService, 'getPhotos')
        .mockImplementation(async () => response);

      expect(await photosController.getPhotos()).toEqual(response);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing i would say is that I would test `getPhotos()`  inside `photos.service.spec.ts` instead of inside the controller.

So your controller test code would look like this:

> `photos.controller.spec.ts`

```js
describe('PhotosController', () => {
  let photosController: PhotosController;
  let photosService: PhotosService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [PhotosController],
      providers: [PhotosService],
      imports: [HttpModule],
    }).compile();

    photosController = module.get<PhotosController>(PhotosController);
    photosService = module.get<PhotosService>(PhotosService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(photosController).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('getPhotos', () => {
    it('should call service.getPhotos()', async () => {
      const spy = jest.spyOn(photosService, 'getPhotos');
      await photosController.getPhotos();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

While your service test code would look like what you initially wrote:

> `photos.service.spec.ts`

```js
describe('PhotosService', () => {
  let photosService: PhotosService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [PhotosController],
      providers: [PhotosService],
      imports: [HttpModule],
    }).compile();

    photosService = module.get<PhotosService>(PhotosService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(photosService).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('getPhotos', () => {
    it('should return a user', async () => {
      const data = ['test'];
      const response: AxiosResponse<any> = {
        data,
        headers: {},
        config: { url: 'http://localhost:3000/mockUrl' },
        status: 500,
        statusText: 'OK',
      };
      jest
        .spyOn(photosService, 'getPhotos')
        .mockImplementation(async () => response);

      expect(await photosService.getPhotos()).toEqual(response);
    });
  });
});
```

That way you ensure a clearer separation between the controller logic and the service logic, and as your code will grow, it will be better.

Also, to make it clearer, you can mock Promises easily in Jest like this:

```js
jest
  .spyOn(photosService, 'getPhotos')
  .mockResolvedValue(response);
```

if it should resolve, or like this to test rejection:

```js
jest
  .spyOn(photosService, 'getPhotos')
  .mockRejectedValue(errorResponse);
```

The last detail which doesn't matter is that your `response` mock has a status code `500` and a status `'OK'`, but it obvioulsy doesn't matter ;)

I hope it was a clear answer, good luck for the rest of your project.